# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar las filas que corresponden a países no comunes entre ambas bases de datos?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo 2 datos que contienen informaciones de distintos paises nombrados DIFERENTES:

```
datos2016$Country
datos2018$Contries
```

Y tengo que eliminar los paises no comunes entre ambas bases de datos y unirlos:

He intentado hacer esto:

```
datos2016 <- datos_2$Country
datos2016
datos2018 <- datos_3$countries
datos2018
total <- merge(datos2016,datos2018)
unique(total)
```

Pero me ha salido Error

Comment: Te damos la bienvenida a [es.so]; por favor haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee [ask]. ¿Cuál es el error que te aparece?

Answer (score 1):

Veo dos maneras en lo que lo puedes realizar la primera es sin instalar librarías que la manera de realizarlo seria la siguiente:

```
#Datos Originales
datos2016 <- datos_2$Country
datos2018 <- datos_3$countries 

#La función %in% te ayuda a que solo te quedes con los valores que están en ambas 
#bases 

 total<-datos2016[datos2016 %in% datos2018]
```